# Fill Postgres column with highest available accuracy based on other column-id/table

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I have a pretty large database with 4 tables:

- post (200 Million)

```sql
    CREATE TABLE public."post" (
        origin_id int REFERENCES public."origin"(origin_id),
        post_guid text,
        PRIMARY KEY (origin_id, post_guid),
        post_latlng geometry(Point, 4326), --only if lat/lng coordinates are available, otherwise add location information as in place, city or country table
        place_guid text,
        FOREIGN KEY (origin_id, place_guid) REFERENCES public."place"(origin_id, place_guid),
        city_guid text,
        FOREIGN KEY (origin_id, city_guid) REFERENCES public."city"(origin_id, city_guid),
        country_guid text,
        FOREIGN KEY (origin_id, country_guid) REFERENCES public."country"(origin_id, country_guid),
    );
```

- place (1 Million)

```sql
    CREATE TABLE public."place" (
        origin_id int REFERENCES public."origin"(origin_id),
        place_guid text,
        PRIMARY KEY (origin_id, place_guid),
        geom_center geometry(Point, 4326)
    );
```

- city (500k) - definition synonymous to place
- country (200) - definition synonymous to place

Index:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_post ON public.post(origin_id, post_guid);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_post_place ON public.place(origin_id, place_guid);
```

The Table post is most important, it has among others the columns "origin_id" (integer, either 1, 2 or 3) and "post_guid" which together function as the Primary key. Similarly, place has "source_id" and "place_guid" etc.

In table post, I have 4 columns:

- post_latlng
- place_guid
- city_guid
- country_guid

I don't always have the lat/lng coordinates for all posts. In these cases, post_latlng should be substituted by location information (of lower accuracy) from place, city or country tables.

I am not there yet to apply triggers to do this automatically, but even manually filling this information takes too long. For example, if I add a new geocode for a place that is already in the place-table, I do the following:

```py
insert_sql = '''                                                                                                                                                     
            INSERT INTO "place" (origin_id, place_guid, geom_center)                                                                          
            VALUES (%s,%s,ST_GeomFromText(%s,4326))                                                                                                         
            ON CONFLICT (origin_id,place_guid)                                                                                                                       
            DO UPDATE 
            SET geom_center = EXCLUDED.geom_center;                                                                                             
            '''                                                                                                                                                      
cursor.execute(insert_sql,(source_origin_id,iPlaceid,iCoordinates_WKT))
```

..afterwards, I run the following code to update posts with this place:

```py
update_sql = '''UPDATE "post"                              
                SET post_latlng = ST_GeomFromText(%s,4326)
                WHERE (origin_id, place_guid) IN (VALUES (%s,%s));
            '''
cursor.execute(update_sql,(iCoordinates_WKT,source_origin_id,iPlaceid))
```

But this takes forever (1 Minute for 1 location, when I need to update 200k locations). Similarly, the other way around: if I add thousands of new posts and (in case no specific coordinates are available) looking up coordinates from tables place, city or country is very slow.

I have the feeling, given my limited experience with databases, I am generally following the wrong approach. What would be a best practice for my example, substituting a missing value (e.g. lat/lng coordinates) from other columns/tables in specific order?

Comment: `WHERE (origin_id = %s AND place_guid = %s)` for your query to make sense, these should be (part of) the primary key, or at least a candidate key, or a (set of) foreign key(s). [please add your table definitions to the question, including indexes, if any]

Comment: Many thanks joop, I added the table definitions to my post above. I haven't heard of candidate keys but looking into them now!

Comment: And, it appears you are processing the query *one record at a time*, which will always be slow. AND: `PRIMARY KEY (origin_id, place_guid),` why do you have *composite* PKs dor each table? Aren't the two key elements both unique already?

Comment: We combine data from 3 services, and under the unusual coincidence that two guid's are the same, we added a 1, 2 or 3 as origin_id to make a unique composite key (origin_id, guid). I will see if processing multiple entries at once increases speed. I also added our indexes above, but doubt this helps much.

Comment: Can you add an index `(origin_id, place_guid)` on table `post`? It is a common way to speed up queries....

Comment: Hi Serge - is this what you mean: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_post ON public.post(origin_id, post_guid);` ? We already have this (I added our indexes above)

Comment: Note: the `ON CONFLICT (origin_id,place_guid)` will also affect existing entries (with the exact lat/lng), and replace these by the surrogate coordinates. I Don't think this is what you want.

Comment: Absolutely correct joop - thanks for pointing this out. At the moment, I haven't started transferring entries which have exact lat/lng but I will need to take care of that in the future.

Comment: `cursor.execute(update_sql,(iCoordinates_WKT,source_origin_id,iPlaceid))` You submit these statements from python, but I get the feeling you have retrieved the actual values from the database. How? From which table?

Comment: I should have explained: the database currently resides in 1-2 TB of CSV files and I am filling the DB. This initial mountain will be reduced to a few CSV files each day, where I plan to create triggers for filling the post_latlng with highest geoaccuracy available.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help @joop and @Serge. I think we found a solution: `CREATE INDEX idx_post_origin_id ON public.post USING brin (origin_id);` and `CREATE INDEX idx_post_place_guid ON public.post USING brin (place_guid);` significantly speed up the process (by x100). We will test if other indexes can increase this further!

Comment: If you want to insert fast, dont insert through a (python) frontend-client. Instead, put the (maybe preprocessed) CSV on the database machine and use `COPY ...FROM ...` . Then -maybe after some cleanup-, add the keys and indexes.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for this hint! The CSV files are kind of messy and need a lot of cleanup, but for some this may work and further increase speed.